# Electron - TypeError var.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

### Seguindo os modelos de estrutura primária padrão oferecidos pela documentação do Electron (https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start), encontrei erros conforme o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação.

Mostrando a informação necessária, a mensagem que aparecia era:
App threw an error during load
TypeError: app.on is not a function
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: app.on is not a function
+ localização no codigo de onde tinha app.on

Answer (score 0):

Eu encontrei a solução mais no sexto sentido de programador que na internet.
Na documentação, a primeira linha de codigo do arquivo main.js, cujo é linkado no package.json : "main" : "main.js", o modulo é importado para uma constante:
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
meu codigo passou a rodar depois de mudar para uma variavel:
var { app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

Espero ter ajudado :) me deu uma boa dor de cabeça.
Se souberem de alguma vulnerabilidade que essa troca traga, por favor, comentem.